# Not able to access my AWS RDS Postgres database from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a Postgres db on AWS RDS. I made sure to wait for the creation process to finish. I then put the credentials in my `database.yml` file like so:

```
default: &default 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: tmlportal 
  username:  <%= Rails.application.credentials[:tml_portal_username] %>
  password:  <%= Rails.application.credentials[:tml_portal_password] %>
  host:  <%= Rails.application.credentials[:tml_portal_host] %>
  port: 5432
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

I'm getting an error when trying to connect like so:

```
// ♥ rails db:migrate:local
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: could not translate host name "tmlportal.c40tsqt6xfgl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:50:in `rescue in postgresql_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:33:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:889:in `new_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:933:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:912:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:873:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:595:in `checkout'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:439:in `connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1121:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:238:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:206:in `connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:111:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "tmlportal.c40tsqt6xfgl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:46:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:889:in `new_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:933:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:912:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:873:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:595:in `checkout'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:439:in `connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1121:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:238:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:206:in `connection'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:111:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/demiansims/Development/tml_info/tml_portal/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I made sure to check my Rails Credentials file to make sure everything is correct and it is. Am I missing something? Perhaps the `username`? I'm using my AWS Account name.

Comment: please check the inbound rule for the security group you have added for your RDS instance on aws console.
Make sure you have whitelisted your EC2 instance IP

Comment: also, username and password should be your database username and password which you have created while initiating and RDS instance

Comment: No sure if I was even asked to create a username but I'll check. Is it the same as 'instance' ? Not to be confused with the name of the database?

Comment: This appears from the error message to be a DNS error.  Are you able to dig or nslookup the database url?